# Data modelling challenges in sanctuary.js

Tags: functional-programming, sanctuary

I am building an app based on domain-driven design using functional programming in javascript. I've settled on the sanctuary.js ecosystem as my tool of choice, but I'm facing some challenges in modelling types.

To put things in context, let's take the code below as an example:

```js
  const { create } = require('sanctuary')
  const $ = require('sanctuary-def')
  const def = create({
    checkTypes: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
    env: $.env
  })

  const Currency = $.EnumType
    ('Currency')
    ('http://example.com')
    (['USD', 'EUR'])

  const Payment = $.RecordType({
    amount: $.PositiveNumber,
    currency: Currency,
    method: $.String
  })
```

My points of confusion follow:

1. How do I define a simple type with sanctuary-def? From the example above, if I wanted to define a **Amount** type and use it in the Payment RecordType definition, how would I go about it? Would I have to define another RecordType for that?
2. I may be wrong here, but my understanding so far is that the ***RecordType*** is equivalent to product types in functional programming. What is the way to define a sum type using sanctuary.js? The ***EnumType*** above comes close, but seems to be for simple values, as opposed to other types. More like, if I had two other types, **Cash** and **Card**, how would I model another type **PaymentMethod** as a choice between **Cash** and **Card**?

I'd be glad for any pointers. I'm pretty new to both functional programming and sanctuary.js so if there's something obvious I'm missing, I'd appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Much thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider payment methods. To keep the example simple, let's assume that a payment method is either cash, or a credit/debit card with an associated card number. In Haskell, we could define the type and its data constructors like so:

```hs
data PaymentMethod = Cash | Card String
```

In order to define `PaymentMethod` using sanctuary-def we need to know how the `Cash` and `Card` data constructors are implemented. One is free to define these manually or to use a library such as [Daggy](https://github.com/fantasyland/daggy). Let's write them by hand:

```js
//    Cash :: PaymentMethod
const Cash = {
  '@@type': 'my-package/PaymentMethod',
  'tagName': 'Cash',
};

//    Card :: String -> PaymentMethod
const Card = number => ({
  '@@type': 'my-package/PaymentMethod',
  'tagName': 'Card',
  'number': number,
});
```

Having defined the data constructors, we can then use [`$.NullaryType`](https://github.com/sanctuary-js/sanctuary-def#NullaryType) to define the `PaymentMethod` type:

```js
const $ = require ('sanctuary-def');
const type = require ('sanctuary-type-identifiers');

//    PaymentMethod :: Type
const PaymentMethod = $.NullaryType
  ('PaymentMethod')
  ('https://example.com/my-package#PaymentMethod')
  ([])
  (x => type (x) === 'my-package/PaymentMethod');
```

Note that because every `PaymentMethod` value will have the special `@@type` property, we can use [`type`](https://github.com/sanctuary-js/sanctuary-type-identifiers#type) to determine whether an arbitrary JavaScript value is a member of the `PaymentMethod` type.

I realize that approximating that one line of Haskell in JavaScript is quite involved. I hope this example shows how the various pieces of the puzzle fit together.

---

We might like to define a case-folding function for `PaymentMethod` like so:

```js
//    foldPaymentMethod :: a -> (String -> a) -> PaymentMethod -> a
const foldPaymentMethod = cash => card => paymentMethod => {
  switch (paymentMethod.tagName) {
    case 'Cash': return cash;
    case 'Card': return card (paymentMethod.number);
  }
};
```

Having defined `Cash`, `Card`, and `foldPaymentMethod` we are able to construct and deconstruct `PaymentMethod` values without worrying about implementation details. For example:

```js
> foldPaymentMethod ('Cash') (number => `Card (${S.show (number)})`) (Cash)
'Cash'

> foldPaymentMethod ('Cash') (number => `Card (${S.show (number)})`) (Card ('2468101214161820'))
'Card ("2468101214161820")'
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `PaymentMethod` is not an enumeration, because the `Card` value constructor expects an argument.

Comment: @davidchambers Thank you. Your response definitely makes it clearer how everything fits. Currently, I create a simple type, say **Amount**, by first creating a data constructor followed by a corresponding $.NullaryType type, which works without any errors. Is this the right way? Also, in which cases would I have needed a $.UnaryType or  $.BinaryType?

Comment: @bob Thanks for your input. Point taken.

Comment: `$.NullaryType` is for defining type constructors that take one type parameter, such as `Array a`, `Maybe a`, and `Tree a`. `$.BinaryType` is for defining binary type constructors such as `Either a b` and `Pair a b`.